# How to choose input method on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, ibus, input, input-method

I have a new fresh Kubuntu installation. I have used Linux Mint and Ubuntu before, those OS have GUI settings for input method, where I can choose ibus or fcitx and type Vietnamese (my language, we use [ibus-teni](https://github.com/teni-ime/ibus-teni) to type Vietnamese).

[image: Ubuntu Input method setting]

I did install ibus-teni, I can run ibus from Search tool, but couldn't type Vietnamese. So how do I setup the input method from default to ibus? Why does Kubuntu not have GUI settings for it like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the `ibus-daemon` does not start automatically after booting into Kubuntu. Do the following steps to rectify this:

- Type 'Autostart' in Application Launcher search bar. This will open the 'Autostart System Settings' dialog.
- Now click 'Add program' button.
- Click 'Open file' button next to the search bar.
- Go to Root -> usr -> bin directory.
- Type 'ibus-daemon' in the 'Name' textbox.
- Out of the three options appearing in the list, select 'ibus-daemon' and click 'Open' button.
- Now you should be back in 'Autostart System Settings' dialog with 'ibus-daemon' selected under Desktop File category.
- Select the 'ibus'daemon' and click 'Properties' button.
- In the properties dialog, open 'Applications' tab.
- Type 'iBus Daemon' in the Name textbox and type `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon start` in the Command textbox.
- Now click 'OK' to come back to Autostart System Settings and click 'OK' here too.
- REBOOT YOUR MACHINE. (VERY IMPORTANT)

---

Your iBus daemon shall now start automatically and you shall see the 'EN' icon in the panel where you can click and select the language of your choice.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! KDE should do this by default, not sure what it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an *Input Method Configuration* GUI tool on Kubuntu, from where you can set IBus.

If you don't find it, you can also do it from command line:

```
im-config -n ibus
```

Comment: Unfortunately after running that line and launch ibus manually (yeah, I have to go to KDE launcher and search for "ibus" and run it), I still can not type Vietnamese.

Comment: Oops! After a restart, now I can type Vietnamese! But there is no icon of ibus showing which keyboard I'm using.

Comment: @Feliks: Hopefully some Kubuntu user can give you a hand about the icon.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as it is only half the equation, the answer is the one offered by Sachin below.